# spacing in a list with css styling

Tags: css

Ive created a box using div class. but Ive been trying to space the row and columnsiV

Ive tried some padding-left and right both it doesnt seem to be working.

```html
<div class="body">
  <ul class="box">
    <li> <a href="">Maths</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">English</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">Chemistry</a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> Commerce </a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Computer</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">Biology</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: can you edit your snippet and add your css you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you aren't just using `margin`? Specifically,

```
li {
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px; // if you want a different margin on the left
}
```

If this is not what you're looking for then please elaborate on your question.

```css
li {
  margin:10px;
  margin-left:30px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <ul class="box">
    <li> <a href="">Maths</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">English</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">Chemistry</a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""> Commerce </a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Computer</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">Biology</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add padding between the rows, you need to add it to list elements. 
Target these by using ".box li" in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
       .body .box {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .body .box li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .body .box li a {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 15px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 400;
            color: #337ab7;
            line-height: 36px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .body .box li:hover a {
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
                <div class="body">
                    <ul class="box">
                        <li><a href="">Maths</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">English</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Chemistry</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""> Commerce </a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Computer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Biology</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```